# FireBase URL not working for Xcode swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

The firebase url is not working does anyone know how to do an alternative to this using the import Firebase

var REF  = Firebase(url: "https://.... my link")

Comment: What is not working about it? You'll probably have a better time if you follow the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the newest version of Firebase, you do not need to point to your URL, so long as you have the App ID in the App Delegate.

Try `let ref = Firebase.ref()`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this ~
NSString *const kESChatFirebaseCredentialKey  =  @"https://YOUR_APP_NAME.firebaseio.com";